# Transitioning the height of a submenu in CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've created 2 fiddles, clicking on the Products list item makes a submenu appear, I need it to transition however. The only difference between the fiddles is that the 2nd link works like I need it to but with a "hack", tested in firefox and chrome but it didn't work in edge.

https://jsfiddle.net/tzswq34a/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/tzswq34a/3/

The only difference in code is that the second link has the line of code below on line 10 in the Javascript section:

```
$submenu.height();
```

Why does querying the height of the submenu make it work?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Let's hope the net doesn't break then aye

Comment: It's not unknown for JSfiddle to go down. Regardless, we shouldn't have to go to an external site to see your code, If you make us do extra work, you're less likely to get help.

Comment: The point of that you can see it in action mate, go easy

Comment: Which you can do in a Stack Snippet...that's what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the CSS Spec currently does NOT cover animations from/to `auto` (e.g. `height: auto;`, which is default). The browser needs an explicit height to which it may transition.

edit: To make it clear: By using `$submenu.height();`, the height is set explicitly and it may therefore transition to it smoothly.

Comment: That height isn't set to auto anywhere, I think it has something to do with the height not being set to 0 immediately

Comment: @Stephen Brown as written above the default  value of height is `auto`.

Comment: Line 10 is not setting height though, it is just checking it, I think that because the height is queried on line 10 the height that is set to 0 on the line above actually works straight away. Isn't that the case though? Are css changes only made after the execution of a function?

Comment: @StephenBrown Line 10 **is** setting the height explicitly. Simply open your developer tools and you will see something like style="height: 38px" in it right after line 10 is executed, which means that it has been set explicitly.

Comment: My friend, elements have a specific height that you can query with javascript, that is where I get the originalHeight value from, it is a integer value in pixels, not auto

Comment: That is the originalHeight value that is set on line 12 (in the 2nd fiddle)

Comment: The line of code $submenu.height(); simply queries or "checks" the value, it does not set anything.

Comment: @StephenBrown It looks like you're mixing the computed CSS value with the actual value. The computed value is (default) `auto`. The actual css value is e.g. 38px, depending on how many child elements are present. See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/actual_value

Comment: Does it matter? The value that is assigned to the originalHeight variable is an integer of 38 and it is assigned back on line 12 to the element after its height had been set to 0, it is not transitioning from 0 to auto, it is transitioning from 0 to 38. I know you cannot transition to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Here it works without the height query if you're interested https://jsfiddle.net/tzswq34a/7/ Kyle Simpson (https://twitter.com/getify) said that the CSS subsystem is "lazy" and that batches work together as much as possible. My understanding of that is that, because the height was set on the ul twice in the same function call only the last value gets set and and therefore 0 was never set on the element.

```
$submenu.height();
```

That line makes it work in link 2 because it causes the first css height assignment (0) to be set on the element during the function's execution.

In the new fiddle the transition height is set inside the anonymous function passed to setTimeout, which the event loop will process after the current function that is executing, therefore setting 0 before that anonymous function gets called.